# Is it possible to disable the ```auto``` tactic in Coq?

Tags: coq-tactic

I would like to check student proofs, but I want to disallow higher level automation. I have looked in the documentation for an equivalent to `Reset`, but could not find it. I tried

```
Ltac auto := fail.
```

However, `auto` was still usable in a proof after this.

Comment: I don't know a way to disable auto, but you can download the students' developments on your computer and perform all kind of analysis on the text to check that some strings don't appear in the script.  I would be happy to discuss you options in a chat.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted something completely in the system to make it self-contained. However, you are right that I can grep the .v file for tactics I disallow.